How to convert Uint8List to List<int> in Flutter / Dart?
Here is my code snippet
final Uint8List iv = Uint8List.fromList('Initialization Vector'.codeUnits);

  // Importing cryptoKey
  final aesGcmSecretKey = await AesGcmSecretKey.importRawKey(deriveKey);

  // Converting message into bytes
  final messageBytes = Uint8List.fromList(message.codeUnits);

  // Encrypting the message
  final encryptedMessageBytes = await aesGcmSecretKey.encryptBytes(messageBytes, iv);

  // Converting encrypted message into String
  final encryptedMessage = String.fromCharCodes(encryptedMessageBytes);

  return encryptedMessage;

and here is the error I am getting
The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'.

Recasting as List<int> in the following manner do remove the error but I do not know is it the right way to address the issue.
final encryptedMessageBytes = await aesGcmSecretKey.encryptBytes(messageBytes as List<int>, iv as List<int>);


Firstly, it can be assigned, so there must be something else fooling the analyzer. Also, there's an issue here: String.fromCharCodes(encryptedMessageBytes); Your encrypted bytes will likely not be mappable to string character codes. Consider a different encoding such as base64 or hex. Finally, never use a fixed IV. You must select a random one for each encipher operation.

This problem doesn't make sense. Uint8List is already a subtype of List<int>; no conversion should be necessary.  Are you sure that you're using Uint8List from a dart:typed_data import?  I am not able to reproduce your problem.  Perhaps try doing flutter clean first.  If that doesn't help, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

@RichardHeap Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I randomized it in this way List.generate(16, (_) => random.nextInt(256)).

@jamesdlin You were correct, previously I have used this package (following the automatic recommendation of AndroidStudio) 'dart:nativewrappers/_internal/vm/lib/typed_data_patch.dart'. Changing to 'dart:typed_data' solved the issue. Thanks.
